# Customizing UISegmentedControl in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

How to change the
       1. selected segment color
       2. deselect segment color
       3. border color 
       4. text color

of UISegmentedControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For selected or deselected:

```
   for (int i=0; i<[sender.subviews count]; i++) 
{
    if ([[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected] ) 
    {               
    UIColor *tintcolor=[UIColor colorWithRed:127.0/255.0 green:161.0/255.0 blue:183.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:tintcolor];
    }
   else 
    {
        [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:nil];
    }
}
```

Manage the textColor with TintColor

I don't think you can change the border, thus you could set a tintcolor for all the SegmentedControl and set a white background, that should do the job.